# DDMF in AS400 source file change, do i need to recreate DDMF?

Tags: ibm-midrange

I have source system file (fileA) and in destination system i have created a DDMF based on source system file (DDMFFIELA). I need to add new column in FileA @source system, Do i need to recreate DDMFFILEA @ destination system??

Answer (score 1):

No, DDM Files are dynamic. The programs that access them will need to be recompiled though. You can test this on your local system by creating a physical file, and adding some records. Then create a DDM file using `RMTLOCNAME('127.0.0.1' *IP)`. You can add or remove fields as you like, and without recreating the DDM file, use `DSPPFM` to view the changes to the DDM file.